# Unsure what to use for a sentinel controlled while loop - Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm currently a beginner in Java Programming.

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my while loop that has a sentinel value.
Everything works until I add the while loop, however it's required so I can exit when the value '999' is entered.

I'm also not sure what to add for the 'if' values.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAverage {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.printf("Please Enter the first number%n");
    int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("Please enter the second number%n");
    int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("Please enter the third number%n");
    int num3 = keyboard.nextInt();

    int sum = num1 + num2 + num3;               //calculates sum
    int average = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;     //calculates average

    while (num1 != ) {
        if (sum > 1)
            System.out.printf("Sum: %s %nAverage: %s", sum, average);

        else if (sum < 1)
            System.out.printf("Sum: %s %nAverage: %.2f", sum, average);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `num != 999` would say as long as input isnt 999, but then you have to update the value before you return to the top of the loop. Youre going to have to reorganize your code to use the loop, and provide us more details on desired input output

Comment: Your `while` loop has no way of changing the value of `num1`. You need to include asking for input somewhere in the loop. Then just put in `999` or whatever value you want as a sentinel. (I'd suggest reading a line of input and comparing it to the empty string as a sentinel, otherwise parsing it as an `int` value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following manner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAverage {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

 int input,sum,avg,count;
 do{
    System.out.printf("Please enter number" + (count+1) + "%n");
    input = keyboard.nextInt()
    sum += input;
    count += 1;
    avg = sum/count;
 }while(input != 999);
 //Do whatever is to be done once sentinel is input.
}
```

Comment: This probably should be reorganized a bit (perhaps with a `do..while`). OP probably doesn't want to include the sentinel value in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the while loop as follows

`while(num1 !=999 || num2 !=999 || num3 !=999)`

|| is used as OR operator. So whenever any input value is 999 the loop wont execute.

Comment: How would I implement this into my code, have the loop output only once and still be able to exit when '999' is entered?

Comment: Yes if the user enters 999 in any one of the variables it will exit the loop
`while(num1 !=999 || num2 !=999 || num3 !=999)
 {
        if (sum > 1)
            System.out.printf("Sum: %s %nAverage: %s", sum, average);

        else if (sum < 1)
            System.out.printf("Sum: %s %nAverage: %.2f", sum, average);
    } `